# rails 2.3.5 action renders json to accounts/images instead of accounts/images.json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I am fairly new to rails and i am having trouble with rendering json files. I have this action in my accounts controller:

```
  def images
     user = current_user #|| current_fb_user
     img_urls = []
     user.images.each do |img|
       unless img.deleted_at || !img.verified_to_s3
         img_urls << img.url
       end
     end

     render :json => img_urls
  end
```

this renders a json, but it renders it at "/accounts/images" instead of "/accounts/images.json" (i get a template missing when i try images.json) as an actual .json file. How do i write the code so i can get a .json file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try putting:

```
respond_to :json
```

at the top of your controller and:

```
respond_with img_urls
```

instead of render :json => img_urls

Comment: respond_with seems to be for rails 3.x, so I cannot use that.

Comment: which version of rails are you using? Have you tried using "img_urls.to_json?" ?